# How to combine OR & AND to work as you think it should do

Tags: mysql

I'm blocked with a very simple Query that it's not working as I think it should do.

What I want to retrieve is all the rows that:

- have status = 4(it could be 1 too) and/or end is less than current time()
- user_id = $id (exclusively)
- segundamano = '1' (exclusively)

What I'm getting:

- rows with end greater and less than time()
- rows with user_id distinct to the specified $id
- rows with segundamano = '0'

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing a stupid thing but I can't see it.

Here you have an example of my generated Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`solicitudes`)
WHERE `status` = '4'
OR `end` < 1289418069
AND `user_id` = '2'
AND `segundamano` = '1'
```

PS: Sorry guys if this is a silly question, any direction will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (`solicitudes`)
WHERE (`status` = '4'
  OR `end` < 1289418069)
  AND `user_id` = '2'
  AND `segundamano` = '1'
```

Comment: Indeed. @Luis, you might find the [Operator Precedence](http://www2.nl.freebsd.org/mysql/doc/refman/4.1/en/operator-precedence.html) of the MySQL manual explains things. AND has a higher precedence than OR, so your original query is interpreted as `...WHERE status = 4 OR (end < 1289418069 AND user_id = '2' AND segundamano = '1'`)

Comment: thanks a lot.. it worked like a charm. In fact I've tried using parenthesis but it seems that I was placing it in wrong place